# pysoem ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, importerror, ethercat

Using python 3.11.6
After using pysoem library, suddenly it started throwing the following error:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pysoem: The specified module could not be found.

Worth mentioning all other projects run fine, only the one using pysoem throws that error.

Deleted and reinstalled:
Python, VS Code, Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (Deleted all, installed ver 2013 & ver 2015-2022)
Created venv for each project separately.
Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Npcap as  pysoem mentioned clearly in their site, fixed the missing DLL's.